# Python string manipulation using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm working on a problem given to us by our professor and I can't get it to work how I want it to work. I should preface this by saying I'm a beginner with Python.

Essentially I'm to write a function that given a string returns the same string as a list with the objects of the list being different versions of the given string.

For example: Hello should return;

```
Hello
hEllo
heLlo
helLo
hellO
```

However we aren't allowed to use python's built in functions that can determine whether a character is upper or lower case such as upper() or lower() and having only really done any "programming" in MatLab prior to this and some OpenCV I'm looking for some help with getting started.

What I've tried so far is something like this:

```
def randRetur(menBok,dicT):
    menBok = list(menBok)
    for i,j in enumerate(menBok):
        if menBok[i] in dicT.values():
            scrambledPws.append(menBok)
        else:
            scrambledPws.append(dicT[j])
    return scrambledPws
```

where my Dictionary maps lowercase letters to uppercase and scrambledPws is simply an empty list to start off with.

However this doesn't quite give me what I want but rather everything is capitalized in the first object of the list, which is where my understanding of how pythons handling of a for loop is very different to me from how for example MatLab handles it. I'm therefore more hoping for some guidance rather than how to do it, as I'm trying to learn.

Comment: you want to make n items from one string where ith letter in item i should be capital?

Comment: what do you mean by built in functions because as far as my understanding goes list and enumerate are built in functions

Comment: @PM77-1 he said he cannot use built in funcctions

Comment: Sorry,  poorly worded on my end will edit, we're not allowed to use the upper() or lower() or any sort of function that can determine whether a character is lower or uppercase.

Comment: I want to know are all given string are capitalized like "Hello", or there will be other string like "hello"(all lowercase), "heLlo"(uppercase not at first), "HEllo"(more than one uppercase), and need different output?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, I turned the string to a list and change the index of that list containing the character to its uppercase version. And then I turned the list back to a string and added it to combos. Then I returned the list of combos.
My explanation is not very good, sorry. But hopefully the code explains it better.

```py
def scrambleString(string):
    letters = { # Create a dictionary containing all the letters and their uppercase
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    "c": "C",
    "d": "D",
    "e": "E",
    "f": "F",
    "g": "G",
    "h": "H",
    "i": "I",
    "j": "J",
    "k": "K",
    "l": "L",
    "m": "M",
    "n": "N",
    "o": "O",
    "p": "P",
    "q": "Q",
    "r": "R",
    "s": "S",
    "t": "T",
    "u": "U",
    "v": "V",
    "w": "W",
    "x": "X",
    "y": "Y",
    "z": "Z"
    }
    combos = []
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        newString = list(string) # I turned the string into a list for easier manipulation
        # The line below swaps the index of string to uppercase
        newString[index] = letters[char] 
        returnString = "" # This is just to the list to a string
        for i in newString: 
            returnString += i
        combos.append(returnString) # Appends that scrambledString to a combo
    return combos
```

Answer (score 0):

see below
The idea is to use 2 dicts that will support lower to upper & upper to lower

```
l2u = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C', 'd': 'D', 'e': 'E', 'f': 'F', 'g': 'G', 'h': 'H', 'i': 'I', 'j': 'J', 'k': 'K', 'l': 'L', 'm': 'M', 'n': 'N', 'o': 'O', 'p': 'P', 'q': 'Q', 'r': 'R', 's': 'S', 't': 'T', 'u': 'U', 'v': 'V', 'w': 'W', 'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y', 'z': 'Z'}
u2l = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e', 'F': 'f', 'G': 'g', 'H': 'h', 'I': 'i', 'J': 'j', 'K': 'k', 'L': 'l', 'M': 'm', 'N': 'n', 'O': 'o', 'P': 'p', 'Q': 'q', 'R': 'r', 'S': 's', 'T': 't', 'U': 'u', 'V': 'v', 'W': 'w', 'X': 'x', 'Y': 'y', 'Z': 'z'}

def get_str_versions(string):
  result = []
  for x in range(len(string)):
    if string[x] in l2u:
      result.append(string[0:x] + l2u[string[x]] + string[x+1:])
    else:
      result.append(string[0:x] + u2l[string[x]] + string[x+1:])
  return result

print(get_str_versions('Hello'))
```

output

```
['hello', 'HEllo', 'HeLlo', 'HelLo', 'HellO']
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. You are not taking into account if there are uppercase chars existing after the current position. Check this out

print(get_str_versions('myTest'))

['MyTest', 'mYTest', 'mytest', 'myTEst', 'myTeSt', 'myTesT']

Comment: @Gouri can you share an example where it does not work?

Comment: I think he is looking for one char uppercase and everything else lowercase. Even the output for "Hello" is also different from what's expected.

Comment: @Gouri see the 'hello' example in the question body.

Comment: the output list has first entry with caps(H) and rest entries have lower(h). Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This question has multiple parts, I can help with one part of it. For this part,
given some character, you need to return the uppercase variant, without using
the string method `upper()`. I am not sure the CPython implementation, but the
Ruby one is here:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fb3c711d/regenc.c#L970-L977

Here is a simple implementation of that in Python:

```
def up(s_in):
   n_out = ord(s_in) + ord('A') - ord('a')
   return chr(n_out)
```

The input should be a single character, with output being the upper variant.
Note that this will only work on ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not even allowed to use functions such as `ord`, which would allow you to check for case using the ascii table, you can manually map all printable characters (a-z) to an alternative-case version, save it into a dictionary, then add the reversed mapping (upper-case to lower-case) to the dictionary, then loop over all characters in a given word using index increment method (but even then, are you allowed to use `len`?).

For each iteration, you create a new string and then replace the current index in a string with a look-up alternative from the dictionary we created earlier.

```
CASE_MAPPING_ONE_SIDED = { "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    "c": "C",
    "d": "D",
    "e": "E",
    "f": "F",
    "g": "G",
    "h": "H",
    "i": "I",
    "j": "J",
    "k": "K",
    "l": "L",
    "m": "M",
    "n": "N",
    "o": "O",
    "p": "P",
    "q": "Q",
    "r": "R",
    "s": "S",
    "t": "T",
    "u": "U",
    "v": "V",
    "w": "W", }
CASE_MAPPING = {}
# Map all lower-case characters to upper-case and also save it in the dictionary
for lower_ch in CASE_MAPPING_ONE_SIDED:
    upper_ch = CASE_MAPPING_ONE_SIDED[lower_ch]
    CASE_MAPPING[lower_ch] = upper_ch
    CASE_MAPPING[upper_ch] = lower_ch
def alternative_versions(s):
    res = [s]
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        alt = s[:i]
        # Replace the ith character with an alternative version
        alt += CASE_MAPPING[s[i]]
        alt += s[i+1:]
        res.append(alt)
        i += 1
    return res
print(alternative_versions("Hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is some code (hope im not late because we had power go out):

```
from random import randint


uppercase = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
lowercase = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

random = randint(0, len(uppercase) - 1)
lowercase[random] = uppercase[random]
print(''.join(lowercase))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input string contains alphabets only.

```
def to_upper(ch):
    return ch if (65 <= ord(ch) <= 90) else chr(ord(ch) - 32)

def capitalize(s):
    diff = ord('a') - ord('A')
    lower_case_word = ""
    for ch in s:
        if 65 <= ord(ch) <= 90: #Caps letter
            lower_case_word = lower_case_word + chr(ord(ch)+diff)
        else:
            lower_case_word = lower_case_word + ch
    for i in range(len(s)):
        yield lower_case_word[:i] + to_upper(s[i]) + lower_case_word[i+1:]

for word in ("Hello", "myTest"):
    print(list(capitalize(word)))
```

[Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLlo', 'helLo', 'hellO']

['Mytest', 'mYtest', 'myTest', 'mytEst', 'myteSt', 'mytesT']